# Summarize Features on a product

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to summarize and combine all product features on a certain product.

With the following formula we are able to have it summarized. But the category and feature need to be splitted.

```
See desired outcome tab in Example file.

Formula used: 
=ARRAYFORMULA(proper(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE({proper(ArrayFormula)(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!F3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!F76:F150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!F76:F150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!F3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!H3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!H76:H150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!H76:H150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!H3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!G3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!G76:G150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!G76:G150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!G3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!I3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!I76:I150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!I76:I150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!I3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!J3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!J76:J150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!J76:J150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!J3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!K3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!K76:K150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!K76:K150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!K3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!L3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!L76:L150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!L76:L150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!L3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!M3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!M76:M150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!M76:M150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!M3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!N3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!N76:N150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!N76:N150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!N3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!O$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!O$76:O$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!O$76:O$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!O$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!P$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!P$76:P$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!P$76:P$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!P$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!Q$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!Q$76:Q$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!Q$76:Q$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!Q$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!R$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!R$76:R$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!R$76:R$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!R$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!S$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!S$76:S$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!S$76:S$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!S$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!T$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!T$76:T$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!T$76:T$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!T$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!U$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!U$76:U$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!U$76:U$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!U$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!V$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!V$76:V$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!V$76:V$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!V$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!W$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!W$76:W$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!W$76:W$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!W$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!X$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!X$76:X$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!X$76:X$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!X$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!Y$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!Y$76:Y$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!Y$76:Y$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!Y$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!Z$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!Z$76:Z$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!Z$76:Z$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!Z$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AA$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AA$76:AA$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AA$76:AA$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AA$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AB$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AB$76:AB$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AB$76:AB$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AB$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AC$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AC$76:AC$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AC$76:AC$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AC$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AD$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AD$76:AD$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AD$76:AD$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AD$3)));char(9))) 
  );ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AE$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AE$76:AE$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AE$76:AE$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AE$3)));char(9))) 
  );iferror(ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AF$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AF$76:AF$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AF$76:AF$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AF$3)));char(9))) 
  );"");iferror(ArrayFormula(
  transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Kenmerken!AG$3&char(9));counta(Kenmerken!AG$76:AG$150));char(9)))
  &" "&
  transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Kenmerken!AG$76:AG$150&char(9);counta(Kenmerken!AG$3)));char(9))) 
  );"")};"(.*)Gewicht(.*)";"");"(.*)EAN(.*)";"");"(.*)Hoogte(.*)";"");"(.*)breedte(.*)";"");"(.*)meegeleverd(.*)";"");"(.*)Uitzonderingen fabrieksgarantie(.*)";"");"(.*)Garantietype(.*)";"");"(.*)Fabrieksgarantie(.*)";"");"(.*)lengte(.*)";"");"(.*)Afmetingen(.*)";"");"(.*)Categorieën(.*)";"");"(.*)Breedte(.*)";"");"(.*)Serie(.*)";"")))
```

See screenshot for how the situation is now: [image]

Here, "Materiaal" and "Metaal" should be splitted.

Example file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gSRb_t1dxEWiPcFYpBuxvsqTtktuu4nLHQotMYplwPY/edit#gid=0

Comment: where in your shared sheet is that formula of yours?

Comment: The formula is from the original sheet with sensitive data. Normally it would be in A1 of "Desired outcome" @player0

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the meantime:

The formula to get this:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!F3&"š"&Kenmerken!F4:F51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!G3&"š"&Kenmerken!G4:G51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!H3&"š"&Kenmerken!H4:H51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!I3&"š"&Kenmerken!I4:I51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!J3&"š"&Kenmerken!J4:J51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!K3&"š"&Kenmerken!K4:K51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!L3&"š"&Kenmerken!L4:L51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!M3&"š"&Kenmerken!M4:M51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!N3&"š"&Kenmerken!N4:N51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!O3&"š"&Kenmerken!O4:O51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!P3&"š"&Kenmerken!P4:P51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!Q3&"š"&Kenmerken!Q4:Q51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!R3&"š"&Kenmerken!R4:R51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!S3&"š"&Kenmerken!S4:S51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!T3&"š"&Kenmerken!T4:T51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!U3&"š"&Kenmerken!U4:U51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!V3&"š"&Kenmerken!V4:V51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!W3&"š"&Kenmerken!W4:W51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!X3&"š"&Kenmerken!X4:X51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!Y3&"š"&Kenmerken!Y4:Y51);ARRAYFORMULA(Kenmerken!Z3&"š"&Kenmerken!Z4:Z51)}
```